# Disable ViewState for asp: Linkbutton

Tags: asp.net, webforms, viewstate

I have two link buttons in my index.aspx

```
<form id="MyForm" runat="server">
                            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
                            </asp:ScriptManager>
                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="subscriptionPanel" runat="server" ValidationGroup="SubscriptionGroup">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <div class="input-prepend">
                                        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></span>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="your@email.com" ValidationGroup="SubscriptionGroup"></asp:TextBox><br />

                                    </div>
                                    <br />
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnSubscribe" runat="server" Text="Subscribe Now!" CssClass="btn btn-large" OnClick="btnSubscribe_Click" ValidationGroup="SubscriptionGroup" />
                                    <li style="visibility: hidden;">
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" OnClick="btnHindiCulture" ValidationGroup="HindiLanguage" CausesValidation="false">Hindi</asp:LinkButton></li>
                                    <%--<asp:Button ID="btnHidden" runat="server" Text="Hidden" OnClick="btnHidden_Click" />--%>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

I want to disable Viewstate for the LinkButton1 for which I am using EnableViewState="false". Still I am getting ViewState Data in Request.Form.

ViewStateData is as shown in below image:

[image]

How can I disable viewstate data for this?

Comment: Disabling ViewState for one control does not mean it will be gone. Other controls are also using it. Even if you set EnableViewState="false" on page level, the input will still be there.

Answer (score 0):

In the .NET framework 4. Put below tag in page directive:

```
 ViewStateMode="Disabled"
```

and use this for each controls that want to save the Viewstate (e.g):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
</asp:DropDownList>
```